# Getting the wrong location data using GeoPy Geocoders with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, geopy

I am very new to python and I am trying to run a csv of zip codes with geopy that will give me the city, state, country. I import the file and run the packet then add a column Address. I want to have all the cities in the city column, state in state column, country in country column etc. I have got the code below to run and splits the address, but not by category just by the delimiter. Could anyone help me with this?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

test_filename='test.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(test_filename, dtype=object, index_col = 1)
df.head()

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="user_me")

from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
Address = geolocator.geocode("Billing Zip")
df['Address'] = df["Billing Zip"].apply(geocode)
df['Address'] = df['Address'].astype(str).str.replace('.', '')

df[['City', 'County', 'State', 'Zip Code', 'Country', ' ', ' ']] = df.Address.str.split(',' , expand = True)
print(df.head())
```

Below is what the output look like:

| Billing Zip | Address | City | State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10006 | Manhattan, City of New York, New York, United States | New York | New York | United States |
| 93049 | Bayern, Deutschland | Bayern | Deutschland |  |
| 95684 | California, United States | California | United States |  |

I would like the output to be:

| Billing Zip | Address | City | State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10006 | Manhattan, City of New York, New York, United States | New York | New York | United States |
| 93049 | Bayern, Deutschland |  | Bayern | Deutschland |
| 95684 | California, United States |  | California | United States |

How would be the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `addressdetails=True` parameter to get a dictionary defining each part of the location separately:

```
# importing geopy library
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
 
# calling the Nominatim tool
loc = Nominatim(user_agent="GetLoc")
 
# entering the location name
getLoc = loc.geocode("Wawel, Kraków", addressdetails=True)
 
# printing address
print(getLoc.raw['address'])

print(getLoc.raw['address']['city'])
print(getLoc.raw['address']['state'])
print(getLoc.raw['address']['country'])
```

If the you enter a location for which any field is not specified this will raise a KeyError, so you might need to except that and fill with Empty/NaN value.